# Show category image on product page

Tags: woocommerce, product

I'm trying to get the image of only the main category on the woocommerce single product page.

However, my code doesn't work.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ){
    if( $term->parent != 0 ) {
        $category_name = $term->name;
        $category_thumbnail = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
        echo '<img src="'.$image.'">';
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the main category image only, but it returns the subcategory image.

Comment: $term->parent != 0 ?

Comment: Is this how you help? If I knew what that part is for, I wouldn't write the problem here.

Comment: Parent not equals zero will always be child category right?